Warning: "exclude follow-redirects from browser builds" when running Axios tests in Jest
I'm encountering a persistent warning related to follow-redirects when running unit tests with Axios in Jest:
Warning: exclude follow-redirects from browser builds

Steps to Reproduce:

I'm using Axios for making HTTP requests in my Node.js project.

When running Jest tests that involve Axios (e.g., axios.get()), I consistently see this warning in the console output.

The tests themselves are passing, but the warning appears every time.


What I've Tried:

I have ensured that Jest is configured to use testEnvironment: 'node'.

I have attempted to mock Axios and the follow-redirects module to avoid the issue.

I reviewed my Jest setup to ensure that browser-specific builds are not being triggered, but the warning persists across all test files.

Running npm ls follow-redirects shows that Axios is the only direct dependency using this package.


My Environment:

Axios Version: 1.7.7

Jest Version: 29.7.0



I have the same problem with axios on vitest.

I also have it :(

I encountered a similar issue when running Vitest on a Nx monorepo. I noticed that my axios dependency resolution in my pnpm lock file looks like this:
 - axios@1.7.7
   - follow-redirects: 1.15.8(debug@4.3.6)

Then reviewing the diff between follow-redirects 1.15.8 and 1.15.9, it seems that the nope.js file that was responsible for the error logging was removed, replaced by a more elegant handling for browser exclusions:

https://github.com/follow-redirects/follow-redirects/compare/v1.15.8...v1.15.9

I tried installing 1.15.9 and the error logging no longer appears with this latest version.
So perhaps consider the following:

performing a package dependency update for follow-redirects, which in my case for pnpm would be pnpm --recursive update "follow-redirects"
if that doesn't work, consider installing follow-redirects as a direct dependency but forcing it to be at least 1.15.9, in my case that would be pnpm add follow-redirects@^1.15.9


If you are using React, as the below answer suggests, Add the following in the
package.json file
  "resolutions": {
       "follow-redirects": "1.15.9"},

